# Execute SQL script from C# and logging errors

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

I am trying to execute a script (.sql file) on a database from a C# Windows application. The SQL file contains 'GO' statements; this means I am using the object SMO.

I am trying to **continue on error** and also **log any error** which might occur during the execution of the script on the database. Is there any way to do this?

This is the code I'm using:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    ServerConnection svrConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
    Server server = new Server(svrConnection);

    string script = File.ReadAllText("upgradeDatabase.sql");

    try
    {
        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script, ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //handling and logging for the errors are done here
     }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two problems here:

First, you call the ExecuteNonQuery method that accepts a string and not a StringCollection. I suppose that this method doesn't recognize the GO used to separate batch statements. Instead, the documentation of the method [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199433.aspx) that accepts a StringCollection states that GOes are recognized

The second problem is the `ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError` passed. In this case the same documentation states that you can't receive exceptions if something fails.

I think that the best approach should be to split your input text at the GO and then build a [StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to pass to the ExecuteNonQuery method and check the returned array of affected rows.
Something like this (should be tested)

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    ServerConnection svrConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
    Server server = new Server(svrConnection);

    string script = File.ReadAllText("upgradeDatabase.sql");
    string[] singleCommand = Regex.Split(script, "^GO", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    StringCollection scl = new StringCollection();
    foreach(string t in singleCommand)
    {
        if(t.Trim().Length > 0) scl.Add(t.Trim());
    }
    try
    {
        int[] result = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scl, ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError);
        // Now check the result array to find any possible errors??
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //handling and logging for the errors are done here
     }
}
```

Of course an alternative is executing each single statement and remove the `ContinueOnError` flag. Then capture and record the possible exceptions. But this will be certainly slower.

Comment: Split with **GO** in the text could break the Script, Imagine that you have to SELECT CATE**GO**RY FROM WHATEVER

Comment: Do you have noted that I use a Regex pattern that anchor the GO to the beginning of a line? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az24scfc(v=vs.90)

Comment: Thank you Steve for your workaround. I am executing each single statement and catching any error if occurs.

Comment: You need a pattern that matches GO as the only 'statement' on the line, case insensitive, and honors the optional `GO nnn` syntax. GO is also actually configurable, there are scripts out there that use `;` as a batch delimiter (don't ask...). For example, see `@"^\b*" + BatchDelimiter + @"\b*(\d*)"` from https://github.com/rusanu/DbUtilSqlCmd/blob/master/trunk/src/SqlCmd.cs

Comment: @RemusRusanu I'm sure you are right, but of course this could be totally unnecessary if the script is controlled/created by the same person/organization that use it. And, probably this is the case, if I understand what that "upgradeDatabase.sql" file name is.

Comment: @Steve: true, but think at everyone that will stumble upon this post later and use the code w/o considering the 'details'.

Answer (score 1):

I really like this variant, which uses the InfoMessage event and handler:

```
        using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            sc.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(sc_InfoMessage);
            sc.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
            Server db = new Server(new ServerConnection(sc));
            db.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(commandFileText, ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError); 
        }
```

You will need to add a reference to the following:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

Comment: This works in conjunction with Andry's answer. You need sc.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not programmer (DBA), therefore I'm not sure.
I assume following can be helpful

svrConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

Answer (score 0):

you can use [smo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms162169.aspx) library, [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129.aspx) is how to add to the project

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("upgradeDatabase.sql");
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

Comment: With your answer, the script will stop execution at the first error. I expect the OP was after all the errors. (not downvoter)

Comment: hi @ArsenMkrt i am try to use your answer but i am getting error on Server server=new.. line can you please tell me which is assembly and namespace for Server.. Thanks

Comment: what is the message of exception?

Comment: May be you are getting an error beacuse you donot have smo dll package  reffrerd in your project @Mohit